# Oracle 11g silent install on Linux CentOS 5.2 x86-32 fails on database creation

Tags: linux, oracle, installation, oracle-11g, silent

After reading the [Linux installation guide for Oracle 11g](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359%5F01/install.111/b32002/toc.htm), taking particular note of the pre-installation requirements; I have been able to record a response file for a silent installation based off a successful manual installation.

The issue is when performing the silent installation based off the recorded response file, the installation procedure will fail when executing the generate shell script for manually executing any steps that require intervention.

Further digging (read `strace`) shows the following exception in an out of the way logfile:

```
INFO: oracle.assistants.server:Internal PlugIn for {Micro Step state:step:1:configuration in CfmAggregateInstance: oracle.assistants.server:11.1.0.6.0:common:family=CFM:oh=/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.1.0/db_1:label=0} failed with an unhandled exception:
oracle.sysman.emCfg.common.CfwExceptionUninitializedParameter: {Parameter:S_SYSPASS in {Aggregate:oracle.assistants.server:11.1.0.6.0:common}}: parameter value has never been set and no default is present.
        at oracle.sysman.emCfg.core.CfmParameterState.expressData(CfmParameterState.java:720)
        at oracle.sysman.emCfg.core.CfmParameterState.expressDataAsArgv(CfmParameterState.java:541)
        at oracle.sysman.emCfg.core.CfmParameterPair.appendDataAsArgv(CfmParameterPair.java:372)
        at oracle.sysman.emCfg.core.CfmArguments.expandOneArgv(CfmArguments.java:92)
        at oracle.sysman.emCfg.core.CfmArguments.expand(CfmArguments.java:61)
        at oracle.sysman.emCfg.core.CfmArguments.expandAsArgv(CfmArguments.java:107)
        at oracle.sysman.emCfg.core.PerformMicroStep.runJavaClass(PerformMicroStep.java:540)
        at oracle.sysman.emCfg.core.PerformMicroStep.executeMicroStep(PerformMicroStep.java:120)
        at oracle.sysman.emCfg.core.ActionPerformer.performMicroStep(ActionPerformer.java:917)
        at oracle.sysman.emCfg.core.ActionPerformer$Performer.run(ActionPerformer.java:1038)
```

My suspicion is that the recorded response file is missing parameters that were supplied during the manual installation from which it was derived. Notably `S_SYSPASS`.

However, even manually setting all password fields in the response file doesn't fix this issue.

The question that I need answered is where can I look to perform further diagnosis of this installation failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the culprit; running the installer with the -noconfig option causes the configuration assistants to not inherit the passwords from the silent installation configuration file.

So, this doesn't work:

```
su oracle -- database/runInstaller -silent -noconfig -responseFile `pwd`/ORA11G_Linux.rsp
```

But this does:

```
su oracle -- database/runInstaller -silent -responseFile `pwd`/ORA11G_Linux.rsp
```

*Thanks for coming in today Oracle.*